# Ajax Custom Post Filter is not filtering

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, ajax

I'm trying to code an ajax custom post filter but the result seems like it's not filtering, and I'm not sure where I did wrong. I'll provide the revelant code below.

**archive-projetos.php**

```
<div class="categories">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="" class="js-filter-item">Todos</a></li>
        <?php
        $cat_args = array(
            'exclude' => array(1),
            'option_all' => 'All',
            'taxonomy' => 'Tipos de Construção'
        );
        $categories = get_categories($cat_args);

        foreach($categories as $cat): ?>
            <li><a class="js-filter-item" href="<?= get_category_link($cat->term_id);?>"><?= $cat->name;?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="content-wrapper js-filter row">
    <?php
    $args = array (
        'post_type' => array('projetos'),
        'post_status' => array('publish')
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    if($query->have_posts()):
        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();?>
        <div class="post-thumbnail-container col-sm">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                <div class="thumbnail-container"><?php the_post_thumbnail();?></div>
                <div class="title-overlay"><?php the_title();?></div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; else: endif; wp_reset_postdata();?>
</div>
```

**filter.js**

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click', '.js-filter-item', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            
            var category =$(this).data('category');

            $.ajax({
                url: wpajax.ajaxurl,
                data: {action: 'filter', category: category},
                type: 'post',
                success: function(result) {
                    $('.js-filter').html(result);
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    console.warn(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**functions.php**

```
function load_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/filter.js', array ('jquery'), NULL, true);

    wp_localize_script('ajax','wpajax',
        array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'))
    );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts');

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter', 'filter_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_filter', 'filter_ajax');

function filter_ajax() {

    $category = $_POST['projetos'];

    $args = array (
        'post_type' => array('projetos'),
        'post_status' => array('publish')
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    if(isset($category)) {
        $args['category__in'] = array($category);
    }

    if($query->have_posts()):
        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();?>
        <div class="post-thumbnail-container col-sm">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                <div class="thumbnail-container"><?php the_post_thumbnail();?></div>
                <div class="title-overlay"><?php the_title();?></div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; else: endif; wp_reset_postdata();

    die();
}
```

I don't think it would be necessary to include the custom post and category but there it goes as well:

```
function projetos()
{
    $args = array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name'=> 'Projetos',
            'singular_name'=>'Projeto'
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-category',
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail')
    );
    register_post_type('projetos', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'projetos');

function tipos_construcao() 
{

    $args = array(
        'labels' => array (
            'name' => 'Tipos de Construção',
            'singular_name'=>'Tipo de Construção'
        ),
        'public'=> true,
        'hierarchical'=> true
        );
    register_taxonomy('Tipos de Construção',array('projetos'), $args);
}
add_action('init', 'tipos_construcao');
```

Any help would be appreciated! I've been trying several solutions and tried to browse other websites but to no solution.

I did console.log(result) in the filter.js to check what was the result, and it just doesn't filter, the result is all the posts.

Thank you, once again!

Comment: From what I see, your `<a>` in the `foreach` loop in `archive-projetos.php` which has the CSS class `js-filter-item` needs to have a `data-category` attribute. E.g. Add `data-category="<?php echo $cat->term_id; ?>"` to that `<a>` tag.

Comment: @SallyCJ thank you for your reply! Adding the data-category attribute to the <a> tag did not solve the problem unfortunely, It still doesn't filter out the posts. But I thank you for your reply

Comment: I forgot to say, in addition to that `data-category`, in your `filter_ajax()` function, switch the position of the `$query = new WP_Query($args)` with the `if(isset($category)) { ... }`.

Comment: Thank you once again for your assistance as the solutions you propose are seriously short comings on my part and it makes sense. I did so as you proposed, but sadly, still does not work, I also tried messing with the `$category = $_POST['projetos'];` as maybe I thought `'projetos'` was the culprit behind displaying all the posts, so I tried to change it to `'category'`  but the output is empty. while if I use `'projetos'` the output is all the posts, also tried to erase the `if(isset($category))` and place the `category__in` directly in the array above, but the output looks to be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How to make your AJAX filter works properly:

1. As I said in the comments, add the `data-category` attribute to the `<a>` having the CSS class `js-filter-item` in the `foreach` loop in your `archive-projetos.php` template:

   ```html
   // * Wrapped for brevity.
   foreach ( $categories as $cat ) : ?>
       <li><a class="js-filter-item"
           href="<?= get_category_link( $cat->term_id ); ?>"
           data-category="<?= $cat->term_id; ?>"
       ><?= $cat->name; ?></a></li>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
   ```

   And if you wonder why add that attribute, then it's because in `filter.js`, the script is reading the category ID via `$(this).data('category')` which is equivalent to `$( this ).attr( 'data-category' )`.
2. In the `filter_ajax()` function in `functions.php`, replace this:

   ```php
   $query = new WP_Query($args);

   if(isset($category)) {
       $args['category__in'] = array($category);
   }
   ```

   with this:

   ```php
   if ( ! empty( $category ) ) {
       $args['tax_query'] = array(
           array(
               'taxonomy' => 'Tipos de Construção',
               'terms'    => $category,
           ),
       );
   }

   $query = new WP_Query( $args );
   ```

   I.e. Switch the position (of the `new WP_Query()` call and the `if` block) and then **use the `tax_query` [parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters)** and not `category__in` which is for the default `category` taxonomy only.
3. Also in that `filter_ajax()` function, replace the `$category = $_POST['projetos'];` with `$category = $_POST['category'];` because your JS script is sending the category ID in a (POST) input named `category` and not `projetos`.

   However, you should always check if an array item is actually set before attempting to use it, so you would want to use `$category = $_POST['category'] ?? '';` or the old way (prior to PHP 7): `$category = isset( $_POST['category'] ) ? $_POST['category'] : '';`.

### Additional Notes

Even though the `Tipos de Construção` does work as the taxonomy name, i.e. the first parameter you pass to `register_taxonomy()`, you should actually use a slug like `tipos_de_construcao` because the documentation [says](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/#additional-parameter-information):

> **`$taxonomy` is the name of the taxonomy. Name should only contain lowercase letters and the underscore character, and not be more than
> 32 characters long (database structure restriction). Default: *None***

So you should try to fix the taxonomy name, i.e. use a slug. It will take time, but it will be a better option in the long run. =)

Comment: Thank you for your help, it works finally! I can understand the problem now and what I did wrong, also for future reference for anyone seeing this, the line  `$category = $_POST['projetos'];`is wrong as well `'projetos'` should be replaced by `'category'` as it was a oversight on my part as well. Thank you Sally once again for your help, you have been amazing.

Comment: Glad my answer helped you! And I've added that `category` thing to my answer. :) Have a nice weekend!